# Svelte is not updating transitive dependency

Tags: svelte

In my component I have 3 variables where `value2` depends on `value1` and `value3` depends on `value2`. When I update `value1` then `value2` gets updated but `value3` stays the same. I am new to Svelte. Is this behavior somewhere documented?

Playground: https://svelte.dev/repl/c092a060a12641489d81e2c5857473bf?version=3.50.1

```html
<script>
    let value1 = 0;
    let value2 = 0;
    let value3 = 0;
    
    function updateValue3(value) {
        value3 = value;
    }
    
    $: updateValue3(value2);
    
    function updateValue2(value) {
// uncomment this to make it working
//      setTimeout(() => {
//          value2 = value;
//      });
        
        value2 = value;
    }

    $: updateValue2(value1);
</script>

<button on:click={() => value1++}>increment</button>
<h1>value1: {value1}, value2: {value2}, value3: {value3}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by ordering the reactive statements differently.

```js
$: updateValue2(value1);
$: updateValue3(value2);
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b6a95f221a1a4c63b93d5216f184d2b3?version=3.50.1)

Svelte is supposed to order dependencies automatically, but because the assignment is "hidden" inside the function, the dependency is unknown to the Svelte compiler, so you have to fix the order manually.

If you have no functions and assign directly, the order will *not* matter:

```js
$: value3 = value2;
$: value2 = value1;
```

---

The fixed order generates this update code:

```js
    $$self.$$.update = () => {
        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*value1*/ 1) {
            $: updateValue2(value1);
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*value2*/ 2) {
            $: updateValue3(value2);
        }
    };
```

The original code generates this:

```js
    $$self.$$.update = () => {
        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*value2*/ 2) {
            $: updateValue3(value2);
        }

        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*value1*/ 1) {
            $: updateValue2(value1);
        }
    };
```

The `dirty` flags are then reset every update and the first condition is never true.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it actually documented somewhere in the official documentation so I can learn all the details?

Comment: Probably not, the limitations of reactivity are a bit tricky. You have to keep in mind that function arguments can be anything, so the Svelte compiler cannot form dependencies within the function. The only thing that matters inside functions are assignments to state.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated your playground with following. It works, I guess you can figure out the difference.

```
<script>
    let value1 = 0;
    let value2 = 0;
    let value3 = 0;
    
    function updateValue3(value) {
        value3 = value;
    }
    
    function updateValue2(value) {
        value2 = value;
    }

    $: {
        updateValue2(value1);
        updateValue3(value2);
    }
</script>
```